# Why Clojure coerces string to character with cons

Tags: clojure, sequence, cons

I played around with sequences in REPL and encountered the following behavior which, atleast to me, is pretty unintuitive. So I evaluated expression `(cons '("1" "2") "3")` expecting it to yield `(("1" "2") "3")` but instead it yielded `(("1" "2") \3)`.

Could someone explain why Clojure automatically coerces `string` to `character` in this case? I'd assume this has something to do with the internal representation of the string as sequence of characters.

Comment: `cons` coerces the string, not to a character, but to character *sequence*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `cons` is a sequence:

> (cons x seq)
>
> Returns a new seq where x is the first element and seq is
>     the rest.

Now you should know that clojure creates a sequence automatically for you if you don't give it one. For instance, calling `seq` (which `cons` does for you) would show you that the string is transformed into a character sequence:

```
(seq "32")
=> (\3 \2)
```

This is done by clojure's [runtime in RT.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/28ecf3ef83acf425589b2aee504174010ec5200d/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L528):

```
else if(coll instanceof CharSequence)
    return StringSeq.create((CharSequence) coll);
```

Instead if you want the character to be treated like a single item then you can wrap it:

```
(cons '("1" "2") '("3"))
=> (("1" "2") "3")
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't coercing String to Character, it is Coercing String to Sequence of Characters, because the second arg must be a collection.

`cons` takes an item as its first arg, and a collection as the second. The collection is coerced to be a list via the `seq` function.

```
user=> (seq "3")
(\3)
```

If you want to use `cons` to prepend the list `("1" "2")` onto the list `("3")` then you could do as follows:

```
user=> (cons '("1" "2") '("3"))
(("1" "2") "3")
```

Perhaps you want `(("1" "2") . "3")`, the kind of non-list cons that you can do in other lisps, but Clojure simply does not have this type of cons pair.